# Python: 3 branched tree

Tags: python, drawing, turtle-graphics

[What i want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RGZfu.png)

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5W9k.png)

I figured out how to make a tree, but it spawns random designs at times. I'd like to know instead how to make a 3 branched tree where everything's in uniform. Thanks!

```
import turtle
import random

turtle.speed(0)
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.tracer(0,0)

def draw_line(x,y,angle,length,color,size):
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    turtle.seth(angle)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.pensize(size)
    turtle.down()
    turtle.forward(length)


def draw_tree(x,y,angle,length,color,size,thiccness,n):
    if n == 0:
       return
    if n <= 3:
       color = 'lime green'
    draw_line(x,y,angle,length,color,size)
    cx = turtle.xcor()
    cy = turtle.ycor()
    draw_tree(cx,cy,angle-thiccness+random.uniform(-8,8),length/(1.3+random.uniform(-.2,.2)),color,size*(0.8+random.uniform(-.1,.1)),thiccness,n-1)
    draw_tree(cx,cy,angle+thiccness+random.uniform(-8,8),length/(1.3+random.uniform(-.2,.2)),color,size*(0.8+random.uniform(-.1,.1)),thiccness,n-1)

draw_tree(0,-350,90,150,'brown',10,30,10)
turtle.update()
```

Comment: Could you provide example images of ***uniform*** and ***random designs*** so we can see what the problem is from your perspective?

Answer (score 1):

I have to say that I like the trees that your program currently generates as they are more like real trees and every one is different.  If we remove the random element from your code, and add a middle branch, then we'll get the one uniform  tree that you desire, and only the one uniform tree you desire:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D

THICKNESS = 30

def draw_line(position, angle, length, size, color):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(position)
    turtle.setheading(angle)
    turtle.color(color)
    turtle.pensize(size)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(length)

def draw_tree(position, angle, length, size, color, n):
    if n == 0:
        return

    if n <= 3:
        color = 'green'

    draw_line(position, angle, length, size, color)

    position = turtle.position()
    length /= 1.4
    size *= 0.7

    draw_tree(position, angle - THICKNESS, length, size, color, n - 1)
    draw_tree(position, angle, length, size, color, n - 1)
    draw_tree(position, angle + THICKNESS, length, size, color, n - 1)

screen = Screen()
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

draw_tree(Vec2D(0, -350), 90, 150, 10, 'brown', 9)

screen.update()
screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: ty! also what does Vec2D mean? and why do we have to put from turtle import

Comment: @mbach21, The Vec2D is turtle's representation of a position -- you don't need to use this, just use a tuple (0, -350) if you want.  We don't *have* to use `from turtle import ...` but it forces the object-oriented API of turtle, rather than the functional one.  Mixing the two tends to lead to problems.